# C# Task not completing (no results in command prompt)

Tags: c#, console, task-parallel-library, task, wait

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _1._8_Starting_A_New_Task
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write('*');
                }
            });

            t.Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

- This application compiles and runs displaying a blank screen (waiting on the task to complete)
- The task stays in a waiting state
- No output is displayed/written to console
- Why not?
- Application stays in "wait" state permanently
- Why?
- Goal of code:  Start a new task, wait for task to complete, exit application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you never start the `Task`. Using the [`Task` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321321(v=vs.110).aspx) requires you to call [`Task.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682(v=vs.110).aspx) on the returned task. This is why it's recommended to use [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which returns a "Hot task" (a task which has started):

The documentation:

> Rather than calling this constructor, **the most common way to
>   instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static
>   `Task.Run(Action)` or `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method.** The only
>   advantage offered by this constructor is that it allows object
>   instantiation to be separated from task invocation.

So the code should be:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('*');
        }
    });

    t.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Spot on Thank you very much :)